# Copying specific bit from register into specific position of different register in single operation

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, beagleboneblack

I'm writing some assembly code for the Beaglebone Black PRU (in the `PASM` assembly language) and I've been struggling with solving a seemingly simple issue.

As the title suggests, I need to copy a single bit from a specified position into a  different register at the same position.
For example,

Say I have

```
r1 = 0bABCDExGH
r2 = 0bIJKLMyOP
```

where capital letters represent existing data that should not be modified. I want to copy x into y.

Now I know a million ways to do this under normal circumstances, but the catch is that I have only **one** operation to do so. I'm able to set some different stuff up beforehand, but that bit move itself should take place in a single operation.

PASM allows referencing individual bits through dot suffixes, for instance `r2.t3` references bit 3 specifically. Through this I figured I could use something like

```
MOV r2.t3, r1.t3
```

But the compiler complains that `use of .T field not allowed here`.
My next attempt was to copy r2 into, for example, r3, clear the relevant bit, and then OR it with the same .t bit. So

```
MOV r3, r2
CLR r3, 3
OR r2, r3, r1.t3
```

But, again, `use of .T field not allowed here`.

That's sort of where I gave up. Documentation on PASM is limited and confusing as it is, and I can't find any good reasons why the `.T` suffix wouldn't be allowed here (`.b` for byte-level access seems to work just fine).

Some reference material I've been using:

- http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Assembly_Instructions
- http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Assembly_Reference_Guide

Comment: I am not sure how your second solution qualifies as "one operation". Clearing the bit and copying it are two operations. If that is acceptable you can achieve the same thing by normal byte/word bitmasking.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm able to do some previous setup. I can copy the register and clear a bit in advance, but once the actual bit copying needs to happen I'm in a loop consisting of four different operations of which only one is available to copy the bit. Before I enter this loop I have OPs to spare, so the first two operations in my second example would take place before this loop, making the third the only operation required to perform the actual move

Comment: On the CPUs I'm somewhat familiar with (x86, Z80, ARM, MIPS, 68000) there's no way to achieve that in single instruction in this way... would the loop be for example some kind of serial-link reader, then some CPUs offer "rotate with carry", so if the reading part will set the carry flag, then you can load it into new bottom bit by something like `rcl` on x86, shifting previously loaded values "up", doing that 8 times, and you have read whole byte from the serial link communication. For "any" bit this usually requires multiple steps (at other CPUs). I don't know PASM, so maybe it supports it?

Comment: @Ped7g So you apparently don't know about ARM all that well, since `[v]bif/[v]bit/[v]bsl` with a single-bit bitmask will easily do this  - albeit in vector registers. Not too surprising, since vector code needs to avoid data dependent control flow.